# str object has no attr keys in BFS

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement a Breadth First Search function with my data set. My data is a list filled with dictionaries and have list values. An example of my data would be:

```
a = [
   {'node1':['node2','node3','node5']},  
   {'node2':['node1','node8','node10']},
   {'node3':['node4','node2']},
   {'node4':['node2','node1','node3']},
   {'node5':['DEADEND']},
   {'node6':['GOAL']}
    ....
    ]
```

`a` would be my `graph` input and my `root` is the first node in `a` so `a[0]`

I'm not sure if my BFS is correct but I am in the process of testing. I will soon have to output the path of the shortest path as well. I was wondering if someone could help me point out where my code is causing this error or how I could fix this problem THANKS!

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 72, in <module>
    BFS(a[0], a[0][0])
  File "test.py", line 60, in BFS
    node = t.keys()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

my BFS:

```
def BFS(graph, root):
    queue = []
    v = []  # set of vertices
    queue.append(root)
    while queue:
        t = queue.pop()
        node = t.keys()
        if t[node[0]][0] == 'GOAL':
            return t
        elif t[node[0]][0] == 'DEADEND':
            continue
        for edges in t[node[0]]:
            if edges not in v:
                v.append(edges)
                queue.append(edges)
    return None
```

Comment: Your `root` is a `str` and `str`s don't have a `.keys()`. How are you calling `BFS`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget sorry jsut made some edits

Comment: as a side note, why not use a single `dict` as your graph? Why a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I wanted to preserve ordering of each node. I want to find the shortest path to the word `GOAL`. Maybe there is an easier way to do this but I thought using a list and preserving order would make it easier for me later to find the shortest path to `GOAL`. I also want to count the number of directed cycles in the graph later. I'm not sure but I thought preserving ordering would also make it easier for me later

Comment: It might make it easier for you to debug, but from a computational perspective, it shouldn't make a difference for finding the number of cycles or the shortest path

Comment: If you want to use a dict, but want to preserve ordering for easier debugging, that's exactly what [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from `queue.append(edges)`. This is because `edges` is a node that the current node connects to, i.e. a `str`. Thus, when you pop from `queue` in your while loop, you eventually end up with a `str` in `queue`, which causes the error that you see.

I think you could solve your problem by replacing that line with this:

```
for d in graph:
    if edges in d.keys():
        queue.append(d)
```